# Inherit python typing structure from base class

Tags: python, inheritance

```
from typing import Dict

class MyDict(dict):
   pass

def f() -> Dict[int, int]: # works
    return {}

def g() -> MyDict[int, int]: # expected no type argument
    return MyDict()

g()
```

```
$ python som.py
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Also pylint returns
`E1136: Value 'MyDict' is unsubscriptable (unsubscriptable-object)`

How can I inherit structure for typing from Dict? Or at least how to allow to type MyClass[Any] and MyClass[Any, Any]?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=generic#typing.Generic

Comment: Note that inheriting from `Generic` will allow it to run, but doesn't properly type hint the inherited methods. I don't know if there is a way to do this properly. I think you'd need to use to `KT` and `VT` type vars used in `typing`, but they aren't available.